# Открытие картинки по ссылке

Tags: jquery, javascript, css, lightbox

Здравствуйте.

Требуется сделать галерею, картинки которой могли бы открываться по ссылке (каждая картинка умеет уникальный идентификатор). Может уже где-то реализовано или есть готовое решение?

Заранее большое спасибо!

**UPD** Примерно также работает открытие фотографий ВКонтакте.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться за что минус вопросу?

Comment: из удаленного ответа: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lightbox+jquery&t=ffab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Копайте в сторону History API. [Вот пример для разбора](https://developer.mozilla.org/media/uploads/demos/j/a/jaydson/ad84b03595ea4fd89d7dd4e4b6357966/history-image-galler_1314856611_demo_package/image-6.html).